# Setting the IfTrue property on ConditionalExpression

Tags: .net, expression

Is there a way to set the IfTrue property of the ConditionalExpression in .NET (4.0 and higher) outside of the initial factory method?

My goal is to have a generic SafeAction class such that the predicate is checked before execution of the consequent actions (IfTrue), but that the alternative actions (IfFalse) are set independently.

I guess I could have my own factory method to generate the ConditionalExpression objects in the manner I need. I was just thinking that these properties (IfTrue, IfFalse, Test) are just delegates and could be reset during the entire lifecycle of a ConditionalExpression object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You have to write your own methods for this.

You could write fluent extension methods for this:

```
public static ConditionalExpression WithTrue(this ConditionalExpression item,
                                             Expression ifTrue)
{
    return Expression.Condition(item.Test, ifTrue, item.IfFalse, item.Type);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works. The idiom's not particular to Expression objects. I'm curious why ConditionalExpression objects were closed from editing (the three delegates aren't executed or even compiled). Anyhow, thanks.

Comment: @skoz: That's called an [immutable object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Among others, thread safety is one reason for making an object immutable.